# I cannot connect to PIVPN

Tags: vpn

Hi I set up my raspberry pi 3 as a vpn server using a script called pivpn. The scrpit makes setting up ovenVPN really easy, the installation went fine but when I try to connect to the server it gets stuck at waiting for server. I set this up yesterday and I was able to connect to it on my android phone using the openVPN app and the .ovpn file I transfered from my pi, now today I cannot connect. Has any have any experience with this script?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the IP in the .ovpn file (line 4) to the local IP of the pi.
If it works your router is probably blocking something.

My pi has 2 IP adresses, the one i set in the config and one that shows in my router log. Both work for SSH but only the IP given by the router works with port-forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Look like the firewall of your router and/or modem are blocking the port that you set up for OpenVPN, you should forwarding the port in router configuration, in my case I setup in the modem provided by my ISP, created rules for the port 1194 that is the default one for OpenVPN.

Note: I saw couples of cases that you are no able to reach the VPN server after forwarding port config in the modem, the workaround that I have been using is allocating the router connected to the modem in a DMZ and handling the security and firewall with the router.