# Cannot connect to PiVPN(open VPN)

Tags: raspbian, networking, vpn

Raspberry Pi Model: **Raspberry Pi Zero W**
Router Model: **Telekom Speedport Smart 3**
TpLink Model: **450M Wireless N Router**

Hi, im using a Raspberry Pi Zero. With the script PiVPN, i wanted to turn the Pi into a VPN, so i can access my home servers anywhere. It worked at first, but i don't know why, I didn't change anything, when i tried it again a few weeks after, i can't establish a connection to the server. I read a similar question([Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60664/i-cannot-connect-to-pivpn)) and an answer suggested changing the "remote" option in the .ovpn file to the static ip of the raspberry pi. It it worked it would probably mean, there was a problem with the router configuration. It worked for me, but only when I am connected to my own network. I already have set a static ip and configured port forwarding but still i can't even connect to my VPN (says "waiting for server" and then stop trying). The Raspberry Pi is connected to a TpLink, which gets it's connection from the router in the basement

Now my question is, what do I have to change in the router settings to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I cannot connect to PIVPN](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/60664/i-cannot-connect-to-pivpn)

Comment: My tp-link router has a separate section to allow VPNs and that overrides the port forwarding.